# Why returned value by a function in Lua doesn't update?

Tags: lua

I have a function like so:

```
function extractValue(result)
    for i, v in pairs(result) do
        v1=v[1];
        v2=v[2];
    end
    return v1, v2
end
```

where I would input something like this:

```
result=findsomething(something,something);
v1, v2 = extractValue(result);
alert(string.format("%f %f",v1,v2))
```

This would output something that is correct, however if I repeat the same code again with updated value (`result`), the value of `v1` and `v2` stayed the same when it should be updated too. Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make `v1` and `v2` local variables.

Comment: Please show the complete code that is having a problem, ie. add the extra calls and so on. In short, post a [mcve].

Comment: It is not clear how your `result` table structure looks like, however, based on your code I assume the `result = {{v1, v2}}` correct?